# How do I get the blog page on my wordpress site to show the text and images in the post editor to look the same?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, web

I want to make my website display a post but it keeps messing up my image when I try to display it.

The content I want to output:

[image]

---

The output that I am getting (the image is not displaying like I want it to):

[image]

---

My index.php:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-lg-7" style="margin-top: 5%;">
        <h1><?php the_title( ); ?> </h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

    <?php 
    endwhile; // end while
    endif; // end if
?>
```

---

Wordpress adds it in a `p` tag (when I inspect the page), not sure how to fix this:

[image]

Comment: Do an inspect element on the picture and check if it got wrapped in a `<p></p>`. It could be an `autop` issue.

Comment: @Ivan86 It does add it in a p tag, not sure how to fix that. I have added a screenshot in the question just now

Comment: Please share a link to the post.

Comment: @FahamShaikh Unfortunately the website is on my local host.

Comment: I am sure you have defined css for `alignleft` class but in case you haven't this is the standard css `img.alignleft { float: left; margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }` suggested on [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Wrapping_Text_Around_Images)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the class reference? That class allows you to specify how many columns you would like to use for the content. You are currently only using 7 out of the 12 columns in that class reference. The first image looks like you are using all 12 columns (full screen), but not the second image.

Try class="col-lg-12” or just remove it.

Comment: The image stay the same when I change the class.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I left it like it is, just uploading bigger pictures

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

- remove `autop` in functions.php

In order to remove the `wpautop` which automatically adds `<p></p>` tags after line breaks, add this line of code to your `functions.php` file:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

More on `wpautop` here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

---

**Solution 2:**

- remove only the `<p></p>` tags around images

Add this custom filter function to your functions.php file and add the filter:

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content)
{
    return preg_replace('​/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

Comment: That fixed the <p></p> tag issue but I am unable to see if there is paragraphs in the post. Is there a way to remove the <p></p> tags around the image only?

Comment: @EduardCloete Ok, I will edit with another solution.

Comment: @EduardCloete even though this last solution will remove the `<p></p>` tags around the image, it still won't add the image to the other `<p>'s`. Maybe your best chance is to use solution #1 and use the method `nl2br()` on your index page to display the content.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the `nl2br()` also puts the image on a new line now.

Comment: @EduardCloete I think I got you a solution. In your wysiwyg editor, click on the toolbar button on the right (the 'toggle toolbar' button) which will open up an additional toolbar. On the additional toolbar look for a button on the right that looks like this `<>` (the 'Source code' button). From there you should be able to see the source code and edit it to keep the image inside the `<p></p>` tags of your content. This solution should work without applying Solution #1 and #2. Let me know if it worked for you or if you need additional guidance.